# How to uninstall Android Studio if installed via Ubuntu Make

Tags: 14.04

I have installed Android Studio using [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) . Now I want to uninstall it.

Comment: `umake` has asked you for an installation path.

Comment: Which command will start the program?

Comment: it doesn't need command to start. It creates icon in launcher.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, if you just type 'umake', here's the output:

```
$ umake
usage: umake [--help] [-v] [-r] {dart,web,android,games,ide,go} ...

Deploy and setup developers environment easily on ubuntu

positional arguments:
  {dart,web,android,games,ide,go}
                        Developer environment
    dart                Dartlang Development Environment
    web                 Web Developer Environment
    android             Android Development Environment
    games               Games Development Environment
    ide                 Generic IDEs
    go                  Go language

optional arguments:
  --help                Show this help
  -v, --verbose         Increase output verbosity (2 levels)
  -r, --remove          Remove specified framework if installed

Note that you can also configure different debug logs behaviors using LOG_CFG
pointing to a log yaml profile.
```

So, going by this, you should use:

```
$ umake android android-studio --remove
```